# Python filter package name from GooglePlay output

Tags: python, search, filter, beautifulsoup

I try to filter the package name from a search in GooglePlay. So the user types in "Facebook" and my script recognize the package name.
I try to do this with BeautifulSoup4. I think it is the best solution for this.

So.. 
here's my code I tried

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'chrome')]

term = "faceboook"
query = "http://play.google.com/store/search?q="+term

htmltext = br.open(query).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

search = soup.findAll("div", class_="card-content id-track-click id-track-impression")

print search
```

Output:

```
[<div class="card-content id-track-click id-track-impression" data-docid="com.facebook.katana" (and so on)
```

How do I get ONLY the package name? I really don't know how. I already read some documentations about BeautifulSoup but I srsly don't understand how I use this expanded.

Thank you in advance and sry for the bad english!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can/should get the value of the `data-docid` attribute:

```
[item.get("data-docid", "n/a") for item in search]
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I get "    ['com.facebook.katana', 'com.facebook.orca', 'com.facebook.Mentions', 'com.htc.sense.socialnetwork.facebook', 'com.twitter.android', 'com.instagram.android'    "

Comment: How do I filter this now? I can't use split there